# Pasting decimal numbers in excel / comma and point decimal separator

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get data into excel using DDE. I get an new value every second from the DDE and use a macro to store every value in the next row. So for so good.

Problem is the decimal separator.

I get from the DDE a value like -5.18834
Using the macro or pasting it into excel, the value shows -518.557 but the actual value is -518557.
The decimal point gets wrongly interpreted by excel. When I paste the same value in notepad I get correct value i.e. -5.18557
I tried deviding the value by 10000 in excel, but some values are 5 numbers instead of 6, so then it's wrong again.

I tried formatting cells, changing decimal separator in excel's options, changed regional setting on my pc but none of those work.
I also tried adding TextFileDecimalSeparator = "." in the macro (found on this website) but that doesn't work either.
Processing the data after the macro has finished is not an option.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can't help you with your code if you don't provide it.  Please see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enumeration, of what you have tried already, seems to rule this out, but i would be very bewildered if the following not would work:

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False

' here do your paste

Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. To be honest, just now, changing the decimal separator in excel options did work. Maybe it has something to do with restarting excel(?). That said, your solution is even better because now this doesn't affect any other excel-worksheet nor the way I'm used to working with excel.

Comment: I suspect it had something to do with that you had only changed the decimal separator from "," to ".", but had not changed the thousands separator and this was also ".". This then causes to such problems. Decimal separator and thousands separator cannot be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - decimal numbers that I passed with macro into cells were assumed by excel as text... So I tried exactly same procedures as well as you did...Didn't help... I tried even the solution mentioned above...it didn't help either. It's a great solution though. Unfortunately it wasn't useful in my case, macro simply ignored this and used other seperator instead. I tried many things and I felt desperate and then I came with this clumsy solution:

```
  Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Macro ignored the setting for the decimal separator so I decided to replace given separator with right one. It works! Like I said it's clumsy solution but as long as it works...

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way without writing a macro. You can change separators through he Excel options.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/10eb503a-2076-4e80-8488-82495e051b30/how-to-change-the-thousands-separator-temporarily-in-excel-2010?forum=excel